# setState is either not updating state or not re-rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

setState is not re-rendering the component or state is not updated at all

```
 handleRowSelectPayrates = (status, nurseCert) => {
let { selectedCerts } = this.state
if (status) {
  selectedCerts.push(nurseCert)
} else {
  const index = selectedCerts.findIndex((s) => s.id == nurseCert.id)
  if (index > -1) {
    selectedCerts.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
console.log(selectedCerts)
this.setState({ selectedCerts})
```

Above is the code which I am using to set the state. I am getting desired data in `selectedCerificates` variable and even after that my state is also changing. But I am expecting my component to re-render.

I am not sure what I am missing. This code is used in some other places also where it is working fine. But here it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, you are mutating state directly :

```
// you assigning state directly instead of copy of that
var  selectedCertificates  = this.state.selectedCerts; // <----- HERE

// this will update the state directly due to the above line
selectedCertificates.push(nurseCert)

// this also
selectedCerts.splice(index, 1)
```

**Updated question**

```
var  {selectedCerts}  = this.state
// selectedCerts is still pointing to state array, it's still not copy of array
```

State is already mutate/changed via `push` and `splice`, and then you are assigning the same state via `this.setState` so as per react there is no change (b/w prev state that you updated and new value that you are passing), so it won't trigger the re-render.

---

**Solution :**

```
// you should pass the copy of array
var  selectedCertificates  = [...this.state.selectedCerts];
```

Comment: check my edited question. I am not mutating I am just assigning the state value to a variable.

Comment: really, dude it's strange how the same code is working at other places.

Comment: as per your updated code `var  {selectedCerts}  = this.state.selectedCerts` , it should look like `var  { selectedCerts }  = this.state`, but that will also mutate state

Comment: yeah forgot to remove that.

Comment: can you please check the code again. this is the exact working code but not in my case

Comment: @AdeshKumar, don't update the question so much or it will be very diff from the original question, there is no way that it work on other places too, you might be checking wrong way. if possible please create a working demo on codesandbox and share, we'll check the issue over there, please do accept and upvote the answer as it solves the issue.